# How to access YAML frontmatter from custom jekyll markdown processor

Tags: ruby, yaml, markdown, jekyll

**How can I extract the YAML frontmatter in a Jekyll Markdown Processor?**

I'm writing a custom markdown processor that can convert plain-text lyrics into HTML for a `reveal.js` presentation. Different songs have different structures. Suppose I have a song that I want to be displayed

```
1st line of 1st verse
2nd line of 1st verse
3rd line of 1st verse

1st line of chorus
2nd line of chorus
3rd line of chorus

1st line of 2nd verse
2nd line of 2nd verse
3rd line of 2nd verse

1st line of chorus
2nd line of chorus
3rd line of chorus

1st line of 3rd verse
2nd line of 3rd verse
3rd line of 3rd verse

1st line of chorus
2nd line of chorus
3rd line of chorus
```

I want to keep the input files into Jekyll DRY (don't repeat yourself), and so I'd love to keep the markdown file something akin to this:

```
1st line of 1st verse
2nd line of 1st verse
3rd line of 1st verse

>1st line of chorus
2nd line of chorus
3rd line of chorus

1st line of 2nd verse
2nd line of 2nd verse
3rd line of 2nd verse

1st line of 3rd verse
2nd line of 3rd verse
3rd line of 3rd verse
```

And use the `>` symbol to tell markdown that this is a chorus. I can write a Ruby extension easily enough to do this for simple songs that have a verse-chorus-verse-chorus-verse-chorus structure (`vcvcvc`), but there are a few songs that have bridges and pre-chrouses as well, and I'd love to have markdown grab this structure from some sort of Jekyll YAML frontmatter (`vvpcvvpcbc`, etc...). Is there any way that people know of doing this? **How can I extract the YAML frontmatter in a Jekyll Markdown Processor?**

This is the Ruby code I have so far, sitting in my `_plugins` directory:

```
class Jekyll::Converters::Markdown::Songify
  def initialize(config)
  rescue LoadError
  end

  def convert(content)
    content =  content.gsub(/\n/, "<br/>")
    content =  content.gsub(/(<br\/>){2,}/,"</section><section>")

    # Populate an array with paragraphs

    # Detect chorus

    # Interleave chorus between all following verses

    # Join paragraphs with <section>

    # Return the HTML verse

    return content
  end
end
```

Comment: As a reminder, the frontmatter is not part of Markdown. In fact, Jekyll processes and removes the frontmatter before passing the Markdown text on to the Markdown parser. I don't recall if the Markdown parser has access to the frontmatter, but I'd be surprised if it did (it is a third party lib which is developed separately after all). I'd start by looking at the Jekyll source code.